# Is Threading Communication Needed Here?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, events

I'm trying to get this code to add something to the screen once a particular time of day is reached. It's rigged to an event. The code works on a single-threaded program, but not with threading, which is what I need. The data is added, as needed, but doesn't show to the screen like it did on the single-thread execution (`timeStack` is a `StackPanel`, `TimeEntry` is a `UserControl`).

Code:

**Mainwindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        SM = new SessionManager();
        SM.NewDayEvent += SplitSession;
        InitializeComponent();
        //Code removed for clarity
    }

    private void SplitSession(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {
        SM.SplitSession();
        string s =((TimeEntry)SM.Entries.Last(x=>x.GetType()==typeof(TimeEntry))).Data.Comment;
        AddSessionStamp();
        entryAdder_Click(null, null);
        ((TimeEntry)SM.Entries.Last(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TimeEntry))).Data.Comment = s;
        this.Focus();
    }
    private void AddSessionStamp()
    {
        TextBlock timeStamp = new TextBlock();
        timeStamp.Text = "-----------" + SM.CurrentSession.Name + "-----------";
        timeStack.Children.Add(timeStamp);
    }
    private void entryAdder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Subscribe to the assorted events
        TimeEntry newTE = SM.addNewTimeEntry();
        //Subscribe to the assorted events
        RegisterToTimeEntry(newTE);
        timeStack.Children.Add(newTE);
    }
}
```

**SessionManager.cs**:

```
public class SessionManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public delegate void NewDayEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs ea);
    public event NewDayEventHandler NewDayEvent;

    private Timer _timer;
    private Stopwatch _clockWatch;
    private DateTime current_time;
    #region Properties
    public DateTime CurrentTime
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
        set
        {
            if (current_time != value)
            {
                current_time = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentTime");
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Session> OpenSessions { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<UIElement> Entries { get; private set; }

    public Session CurrentSession
    {
        get
        {
            return current_session;
        }
        set
        {
            if (current_session != value)
            {
                current_session = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentSession");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion


    public SessionManager()
    {
        _clockWatch = new Stopwatch();
        _timer = new Timer(1000);//one second
        _timer.Elapsed += timerElapsed;

        //Code removed for clarity
        current_time = new DateTime();
        CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
        _timer.Start();
    }


    #region Methods
    #region Event Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Registered to Timer.Elapsed Event
    /// (See constructor)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public void timerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
        if ((CurrentTime.TimeOfDay.Hours == 13 &&
            CurrentTime.TimeOfDay.Minutes == 23 &&
            CurrentTime.TimeOfDay.Seconds == 0) &&
            NewDayEvent != null)
        {
            NewDayEvent(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Class Methods

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string member_name = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(member_name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #endregion
    public void SplitSession()
    {
        Session prevSesh = CurrentSession;
        OpenSessions.Add(new Session());
        CurrentSession = OpenSessions.Last();
        current_session.addComment(
            ((TimeEntry)Entries.Last(
            x => x.GetType() == typeof(TimeEntry))
            ).Data.Comment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handler functions are executed in the same Thread as the one who raised the event. Problem is you can't update the UI from another thread that the Dispatcher thread. You'll need to execute the callback function (or at least the update part) inside a Dispatcher Invoke or BeginInvoke:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
    //your UI update
}));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where the comment is, is that where I put NewDayEvent()? or the SplitSession Method code?

Comment: Either will work but it would be illogical to execute the event raising in the Dispatcher thread because it's a consumer specific behavior. So you should wrap the SplitSession content inside the Invoke